# Navigate to folder inside src

Tags: java, eclipse

I have created project that copies exe file that is inside project/src/drivers folder to project folder.
Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("src\\drivers\\test.exe");
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(".\\test2.exe");
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        int b = 0;
        while ((b = bis.read()) != -1) {
            bos.write(b);
        }
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
```

But when i create executable jar, i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\drivers\test.exe (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Why system cannot find my exe file inside jar? How can i navigate to my driver folder inside jar?

Here is my jar file opened in winrar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKBip.jpg

Comment: Is `drivers\test.exe` actually packed into you jar?

Comment: Your `src` folder is not part of the classpath when you run the code

Comment: Yes, i have drivers folder with test.exe inside the jar.

Comment: How can i then copy exe file from jar?